# How could I include these requires among multiple scripts

Tags: ruby

I have lots of scripts need to include the same header.

What's the better way to  include them in every script

```
    # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require 'yaml'
    require "json"
    require 'pry'
    require "selenium-webdriver"
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'active_support/all'
    require 'yaml'
    require 'date'
    require 'awesome_print'
    require 'mongo'
    require File.expand_path('./form_action.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('./schedule_manager.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../common_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../mongodb_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../webdriver_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/db_manager.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/app_util.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/schedule_manager_base.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/class_template.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    include Mongo
    include MongodbHelper
    include AppUtil
```

## Project folder structure

I will include the `common_includes` in `client1.rb`,

But the `SIBLINGS` not work.

```
├── common_helper.rb
├── common_includes.rb
├── config
│   ├── database.yml
│   └── schedule.rb
├── client1
│   ├── config.yml
│   ├── client1.rb
│   └── schedule_manager.rb
└── webdriver_helper.rb
├── lib
│   ├── app_util.rb
│   ├── class_template.rb
│   ├── db_manager.rb
│   └── schedule_manager_base.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

Put smth like following:

```
REQUIRES = %w(yaml json pry selenium-webdriver nokogiri active_support/all yaml date awesome_print mongo)
SIBLINGS = %w(form_action schedule_manager)
COMMON = %w(common_helper mongodb_helper webdriver_helper db_manager.rb lib/app_util lib/schedule_manager_base lib/class_template.rb)
INCLUDES = %i(Mongo MongodbHelper AppUtil)

REQUIRES.each &method :require
SIBLINGS.each do |f|
  File.expand_path("./#{f}.rb", File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
COMMON.each do |f|
  File.expand_path("../#{f}.rb", File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
module CommonIncludes
  def self.included base
    INCLUDES.each { |inc| base.include Kernel.const_get(inc) }
  end 
end
```

into a very file `common_includes.rb` and everywhere you need it, call:

```
require 'common_includes'
include CommonIncludes
```

This is more or less common approach to require/include in case you need to specify the file list explicitly one by one.

**NB** To manage external dependencies, *everyone* wants to use bundler, as mentioned Mike Slutsky around.

**UPD** Don’t hesitate to use `Dir["./*.rb"]` to collect *all* the files for a given directory.

Comment: `SIBLINGS` won't work please see my folder structure thanks :)

Comment: Use `require_relative` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are looking for a way that you can include all these headers without having to copy and paste them all over the place.

One way you can achieve this is to put all these headers into one file, and in your scripts just include that file:

For example, in headers.rb:

```
   # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require 'yaml'
    require "json"
    require 'pry'
    require "selenium-webdriver"
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'active_support/all'
    require 'yaml'
    require 'date'
    require 'awesome_print'
    require 'mongo'
    require File.expand_path('./form_action.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('./schedule_manager.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../common_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../mongodb_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../webdriver_helper.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/db_manager.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/app_util.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/schedule_manager_base.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require File.expand_path('../lib/class_template.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    include Mongo
    include MongodbHelper
    include AppUtil
```

Then your scripts:

```
require 'path/to/headers'
```

Comment: This won’t work as expected for includes. Read: this answer is wrong and does not do what is requested by OP.